# How do ML ranking algorithms like LambdaMART generalize for unseen queries?

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

I am currently studying Learning to Rank algorithms like RankNet, LambdaRank, LambdaMART. I want to use them to recommend items for a given query. Thus, I want to learn to rank items for queries. I have features for both the queries and the items.

I looked into the [theory](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/e.kanoulas/wp-content/uploads/Lecture-8-1-LambdaMart-Demystified.pdf) and [implementation](https://github.com/lezzago/LambdaMart) of LambdaMART. I do not get how to use it for queries that are not in the training dataset. The implementation does not even provide a way to input query features:

```
training_data: Numpy array of documents (default: None)
               Each document’s  format is [relevance score, query index, feature vector]
```

How is that useful in any reasonable application? When I think of web search, it is impossible to include every possible search in the training dataset.

*How do the popular ranking algorithms generalize for unseen queries?*

Comment: The queries are not in input to the model, but just give information on which documents should be paired. Only training points in the same query are paired and evaluated, not points from different queries. So a set of unseen queries only says which documents should be confronted to each other, and which not. There is nothing to learn about the query itself.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Assume I use learning-to-rank to rank webpages given some input data, e.g. a search query. The actual search query string is very relevant and there is a lot to learn about it.

Comment: I am by no mean an expert but for what I understand it is not an essential part of the algo. I guess if the structure of the query is relevant for the result then you can just give it in input together with the document pair, and that part of the input will be the same for all documents related to that query.

Comment: In this way the network will learn the relationship between the query space and the document space. It will have 2 inputs, one with doc1 and query and one with doc2 and query, and will return which doc maps better to the query. A new query is just a new point in query space. It will generalise in the same way that it can generalise to unseen documents. If the query is just a representation of which documents should be paired, then you can omit it from the input. I am limiting to a pairwise comparison for simplicity.